# Automate publishing to Map Server

Tags: postgresql, web-mapping, fme-form, mapping

I recently been using FME to publish feature layers but have now had to move to map image layers because of the issue around grouping limitations with feature layers.

I am now trying to work out how is the best way once I update a geodatabase or a enterprise database with data, how it can be automatically published as a map service? Is there a straight forward process to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Thanks Ian - Sorry i was just looking initially for some advice on what route to take.